# What would the big O notation for this function?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

What would be the worst time complexity big O notation for the following pseudocode? (assuming the function call is an O(1)) I'm very new to big O notation so I'm unsure of an answer but I was thinking O(log(n)) because the while loop parameters multiplied by 2 each time or would that just be O(loglog(n))? Or am I wrong on both counts? Any input/help is appreciated, I'm trying to grasp the concept of big O notation for worst time complexity which I just started learning. Thanks!

```
i ← 1
while(i<n)
    doSomething(...)
    i ← i * 2
done
```

Comment: Looks like O(log(n)) to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `i` is doubling every time, then the number of times the loop will execute is the number of times you can double `i` before reaching `n`. Or to write it mathematically, if `x` is the number of times the loop will execute we have `2^x <= n`. Solving for `x` gives  `x <= log_2(n)`. Therefore the number of times the loop will execute is `O(log(n))`

Comment: Would the big O of this algorithm change if the algorithm function called within the loop was of a big O of O(n), O(m), or O(m!) where m is an independent size variable? Or does it not matter what the algorithm function called is?

Comment: Yes it would. If the inner function were `O(n)` then the entire process would be `O(n log(n))`

Answer (score 5):

`i` is growing exponentially, thus loop will be done in logarithmic time, *O(log(n))*

Answer (score 3):

O(log(n)) is correct when you want to state the time complexity of that algorithm in terms of the number n. However in computer science complexity is often stated in the size of the input, i.e. the number of bits. Then your algorithm would be linear, i.e. in O(k) where k is the input size.

Typically, other operations like addition are also said to be linear not logarithmic. A logarithmic complexity usually means that an algorithm does not have to consider the complete input. (E.g. binary search).

If this is part of an exercise or you want to discuss complexity of algorithms in a computer science context this difference is important.

Also, if one would want to be really pedantic: comparison on large integers is not a constant time operation, and if you are considering the usual integer types, the algorithm is basically constant time as it only needs up to 32 or 64 iterations.

Comment: I can sort of see where you're coming from, but what would be the "k" in this case?

Comment: The number of bits required to represent the number n, which is basically log_2(n)+1 rounded downwards. So in the end, both statements give you the same amount of information. Just the "length of input" variant is more common as it transfers better to other kinds of data. Is an algorithm finding a character in a String more "expensive" than your algorithm? I would say from an abstract point of view it is not.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I'd say that in this particular case, since the algorithm presented appears to be purely hypothetical (and probably constructed simply to explore Big-O notation), a time complexity in terms of *n* is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I just wanted to add this for completeness, and to encourage to think about the details as they matter a lot, when you find such a statement somewhere about some algorithm.